# How to expand dropdowns in IE?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

In most Windows applications, you can use <kbd>F4</kbd> to expand a currently focused dropdown. How do I do that in IE? <kbd>F4</kbd> focuses on the address bar.

Comment: For me on IE10, `F4` brings down the drop down menu and highlights the text, where as `ALT+D` or `CTRL+L` only highlights the text in the address bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ALT + (down arrow) also works across all Windows applications. (down arrow) on its own cycles the currently-focused drop down through each item. ALT+(down arrow) causes the entire drop down to, well, drop down. I just tried this on the Hotmail sign-up page and it worked there to cause the Date Selection drop down menus to expand.